# Commas in CSV values import into Highcharts Editor

Tags: csv, highcharts, highcharts-editor

Using the Highcharts editor demo,

http://editor.highcharts.com/full.html

To get some sample data, for the first step in the wizard, click 'sample data' and 'categorised, 4 data columns' (the first option).

Then replace

Jan,7,-0.2,-0.9,3.9

with

"A,B",7,-0.2,-0.9,3.9

and press import. Highcharts complains with error 14:
http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14

It looks like the CSV format isn't fully supported, i.e. commas inside values supported by quotes. Are there any plans to allow that?

Comment: Highcharts editor bases on Highcharts data module which does not have full support for csv format - http://jsfiddle.net/v9d3pbgv/

There is an open ticket on Highcharts repo for enhancing that behaviour - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an issue on Highcharts repository:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6503

As an alternative you can use different delimeter:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.itemDelimiter